# How to pass max iterations to fmin in scipy brute optimization

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to do a brute force optimization in SciPy.

(imported scipy.optimize as spo)

> res_brute = spo.brute(self.minimize_this,
>   rranges, full_output=True, finish=spo.fmin)

My question is: How do I make sure spo.fmin stops after N iterations? I can't seem to pass it any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

[`brute`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html) doesn't have an option to pass additional arguments to the minimization function, so to override the default behavior, you'll have to create a wrapper of `fmin` and in the wrapper, set the `maxiter` argument.  The wrapper is then passed to `brute` as the `finish` argument.

For example, suppose we want the minimum of

```
def func(x):
    return np.cos(3*x) + 0.25*(x-5)**2
```

on the interval [0, 10], and we want to limit the maximum number of iterations of `fmin` to 4.  Here's how that can be done (in an ipython session).

First, the imports:

```
In [102]: import numpy as np

In [103]: from scipy.optimize import brute, fmin
```

Define the objective function:

```
In [104]: def func(x):
     ...:     return np.cos(3*x) + 0.25*(x-5)**2
     ...:
```

Call `brute`, using a lambda expression for the `finish` argument.  The lambda expression just passes its arguments on to `fmin`, along with `full_output=True` and `maxiter=4`.  (Instead of a lambda expression, you could define a separate function that does the same thing.)

```
In [110]: brute(func, [slice(0, 10, 0.1)], finish=lambda func, x0, args=(): fmin(func, x0, args, full_output=True, maxiter=4))
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
Out[110]: array([ 5.2325])
```

For comparison, here's the result when `maxiter=100`:

```
In [111]: brute(func, [slice(0, 10, 0.1)], finish=lambda func, x0, args=(): fmin(func, x0, args, full_output=True, maxiter=100))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -0.986810
         Iterations: 13
         Function evaluations: 26
Out[111]: array([ 5.2235498])
```

And when we don't use `maxiter` in the call to `fmin` in the lambda expression:

```
In [112]: brute(func, [slice(0, 10, 0.1)], finish=lambda func, x0, args=(): fmin(func, x0, args, full_output=True))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -0.986810
         Iterations: 13
         Function evaluations: 26
Out[112]: array([ 5.2235498])
```

As expected, that result is the same as not overriding `finish`:

```
In [113]: brute(func, [slice(0, 10, 0.1)])
Out[113]: array([ 5.2235498])
```